# Align photos and captions in a grid

Tags: layout, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align four pictures with their captions in a square grid.

I'm using the following HTML code:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="post-block">
        <img src="img1.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">caption1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-block">
        <img src="img2.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">caption2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-block">
        <img src="img3.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">caption3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-block">
        <img src="img4.jpg" />
        <div class="caption">caption4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS code:

```
.post-block {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If images and captions are the same size everything is ok, but when they are different I get this (an example):

I've tried to align images and captions of different sizes using CSS with no success. I need something like this:

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use separate block elements at the same DOM level for the image and the caption to achieve what you've shown in the "RIGHT" image.  Right now your caption DIV is nested inside the image DIV, and that's gonna do what you've shown.  The caption DIV needs to be **outside** the image DIV.

Comment: so, do I need to wrap the img tag inside another div tag, separate from the caption?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want two separate div wrappers around each 2 photos.. 
Then align images vertically to bottom.
[Vertical align images to bottom](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)

```
<div class="myWrapClass">
        <img src="my image">
        <img src="my image">
    </div>
    <div class="myWrapClass">
        <img src="my image">
        <img src="my image">
    </div>
```

then set the styling via inline or your css file

```
<div style="vertical-align:bottom;">
```

or

```
.myWrapClass{
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

check out this site... Use the css properties there to keep it responsive
[Example](http://www.aachips.com/paintedRecoveryMedallions.html)

Comment: but, I need the grid to be responsive, and I think that your solution is not